# React: why is double brace syntax, style{{..}}, required for inline styles

Tags: reactjs

My question involves styling react components inline.

I understand that within JSX `{variableName}`, braces are needed to reference any JS variable or expression.

So, adding an inline style using the following construct makes sense to me. The desired style is stored in a JavaScript variable, then referenced within the JSX "tag" as `style={divStyle}`

```
const divStyle = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${avatarURL})`,
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return (
    <div className='avatar' style={divStyle}>
      Hello World!
    </div>;
  )
}
```

But I do not see the connection with the syntax of `style={{..}}` when the style is typed directly into the JSX "tag" as in the following:

```
function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return (
    <div className='avatar' style={{backgroundImage: `url(${avatarURL})`}}>
      Hello World!
    </div>;
  )
}
```

Can someone explain the logic behind the `style={{..}}` construct ?

I see this in docs and other reference materials, but I haven't seen any explanation, it's just passed over as though obvious.

As this was not an obvious extension of the JS expression rule to me, I was using only a single set of braces, and getting errors.

Comment: It's just an object literal. The first pair of braces denotes a js expression. The second pair is the start and end braces of the object. It's more obvious when you're defining multiple style properties.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're returning an object. So the outer `{}` brackets are for returning a variable, and the inner `{}` brackets are for creating an object.

Reformat it and it might make more sense:

```
style={
  {
    backgroundImage: `url(${avatarURL})`,
    color: #ffffff,
    fontSize: 16px
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not realize that we using objects here.  Ok, now that I look at it, we're obviously creating a list of key value pairs in JS.  I just never thought about "css" in that way. But actually, it's an object we're passing into a JS createElement method, through syntatic sugar of JSX.  WoW. Thanks !!