# I cannot retrieve values from another modules

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I don't know how to pass values between two modules. It will be very kind if you help me out. Another doubt is, in **code A**  while writing value for style for text input why there are four curly braces?

**Code A**

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View,Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import data from './localserver';

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (

    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent:'space-around',alignItems:'center'}}>
      <TextInput
            style={{height: 40}}
            placeholder="Enter your mobile no"
            placeholderTextColor={data.details}
          />
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
    </View>

      );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => PizzaTranslator);
```

**Code B**

```js
import React from 'React'
var details = {
  primarysColor: '#FFC12E',
  secondarysColor: '#111E27'
}

export default details;
```

[image: this is my error]

[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KikGA.jpg)

Comment: [Why is double brace syntax style required for inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950833/react-why-is-double-brace-syntax-style-required-for-inline-styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned path till folder 
And wanted to access file. This is because you are getting error
**Try with './localserver/data'**

If you dont want to mention /data you need to add index.js file under localserver folder and export data file in index file

Answer (score 0):

> In code A while writing value for style for text input why there are
>   four curly braces

- First couple of curly braces are for JSX, cause once you start wrting JS (the style object in your case) inside your JSX, you're going to need to encapsulate them between `{ }`
- Internal curly braces are for style `object`.

And about passing you data between modules ... the file name `data.js` is missing in your `import` statement

```
import data from './localserver/data';
```